# TextView Clickeable Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito hacer un TextView Clickeable, pero el texto de este no es siempre el mismo por lo que no lo puedo hardcodear en el xml, entonces necesito asignarlo dinamicamente, lo hago de esta manera :

```
aux = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPagWeb);
aux.setText(c.getString(0)); //Cursor c saca la pag web de una base de datos
aux.setClickable(true);
```

Pero el texto queda en gris no pudiendo clickearlo.

Comment: prueba poniendolo aux.setFocusable(true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion erae poner en el .xml de la activity debia poner:
autoLink:"all" o "web" // Es depende el gusto de cada uno, o para lo que lo use
//junto a:
clickable="true"

Habia olvidado de poner autoLink espero que les sirva.

Comment: Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 1):

una forma es así:

```
 aux.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // tu código
        }
    });
```

Comment: y como codifico que abra el navegador predeterminado con esa pagina de URL

Comment: Ya esta, me habia olvidado el autoLink en el xml, gracias por tomarte el tiempo Igual

Comment: pues deberías publicar como lo corregiste, esto le podría servir a otros